# Error returning a struct

Tags: solidity

I'm taking this free course on freecodecamp and as I was trying to follow along with the code I got stuck on this code. After I deploy that contract it's supposed to implement the person struct but each time I compile the code and deploy it, it's not returning the struct. I provided a screenshot of the code. thanks in advance

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0

contract SimpleStorage{

    //This will get initialized to 0!
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    People public person = People({favoriteNumber: 2, name: "Yannick"});

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve()public view returns(uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Yannick! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! I've changed your title because it is too generic, most question in the forum are about solidity. What do you mean by " it's not returning the struct"? Are you calling a function and it fails, it is returning something you are not expecting? How are you testing things? hardhat, truffle, brownie, remix.

Comment: where is the method that should return struct?

Comment: hey guys ...thanks for your help ...I was using remix and I was using the wrong compiler version at the top